# Cycles. The object doesn't show the material I want, but other, how do I delete unwanted materials?

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials

I modeled **Plastic Plate** in Blender, then added **Clear Glass Material**, also render in Cycles, but it doesn't show the glass material. See the result in the image below at the left-hand side. My question continue at the second or **Image 2.**

Image 1.
[image: See the result in the image below at the left-hand side]

2. Here I render the object in Blender, everything was fine to me. Why it can't work in Cycles, or how to do make it to work?

Image 2.
[image]

3. Then in the image below; how to delete these materials. **See Image 3.**

Image 3.
[image]

Comment: Hello :). **1.** Cycles materials work differently than Blender Internal, and there's a dedicated Glass shader **2.** Click the 'minus' icon in the sidebar

Comment: And also, please split this post into two separate questions :). You'll get answers for both and it keeps the site nice and tidy :).

Comment: @Jachym Michal I hope I didn't misunderstand your direction; **1.** I modeled the Object in Blender, then **2.** I downloaded the **Clear Glass** from Here [link] (http://blendermada.com/materials/detail/79-clear-glass-material/) I later find out that it was for your Cycles.

Now, before I could use this Material, I must model the Object in Cycles?

Comment: You don't need to model it again :). Just switch to cycles and use a *Glass BSDF Shader*.

Answer (score 0):

just make sure no Object use your material you want to delete . Unset from all objects in your scene .
then go to file>Clean up > purge all
save your project
close and re-open .
Do it times to clear Scene completely .

Comment: I didn't know where to get **Clean up** as you directed. I actually have the same Materials in other projects, which I did not like to see them there. So, I want to get rid of them. And I wouldn't mind to start afresh to add new materials.

Comment: Do you use a library ? read this link : https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/materials/material_library.html

Comment: Now I have really understood how to Remove or Delete Materials from the material-box. To **Shift+Click + x** to **Unlink data-block**. Then I Click the -Minus button, and Saved, Close Blender and Reopen it, and it was gone.

Answer (score 0):

1. To remove materials from an object, click the minus icon
2. For glass in Cycles, simply use the *Glass BSDF Shader*

[image]

Comment: Oh yeah, I noticed that from the Surface; I used **Diffuse BSDF** but when I used your preference, it worked, but the Object is darker. So I would like to know the easy way to make it more bright, at least to look like realistic Plastic Material. Though it is called Glass, but it could work for Transparent Plastic right?

Comment: Sure, clear plastic is very similar to glass :). Please, post a new question about it. (To keep the site nice and tidy.)